# bar Button Item text Will change when select in moonIcon like Font Awesome in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4, font-awesome, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle

I used this code to using moonIcon Font like font Awesome in my app for `UIBarButtonItem` in `navigationController`

```
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: publicSVGAssets().menu, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuAction))
menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(NSDictionary(dictionary: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "icomoon", size: 25)!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]) as? [NSAttributedStringKey : Any], for: [])
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

this will working well But the problem is that when user selecting the button the Icon will change like the picture below 
[image: as you see in the photo the right Bar Button Image will change to question mark But I want that Menu Image like when the button Does not selected]

Comment: Consider using `let` constants to contain the values of the things you need for the parameters going into the `menuButton` constructor method and the `setTitleTextAttributes` method. This will do you worlds of help when trying to debug. You can then step line-by-line through the `let` constant assignments and ensure each value is correct before they are then plugged into the constructor and text attributes methods. (See my answer below for an example of this). In my opinion, it would be cleaner looking code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be something as simple as the font attribute is only being applied when the state of the button is `.normal` (as you specify).

You may need to specify that all states of the button get these title text attributes applied, like so:

```
let title = publicSVGAssets().menu
let style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain
let selector = #selector(menuAction)
let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: style, target: self, action: selector)

let font = UIFont(name: "icomoon", size: 25)
let attributesDictionary: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any]? = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font!, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]
menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributesDictionary, for: .normal)
menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributesDictionary, for: .selected)
menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributesDictionary, for: .highlighted)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton
```

Tapping the button will change its state. This could be why you see it change the icon when you tap it.

Note: if you ever need to show the button in some other state (such as `disabled`) you will need to assign these same title text attributes for that state as well.

...for example:

```
menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributesDictionary, for: .disabled)
```

(Note: this is a similar answer to the one @Satish gave).

Comment: I received this error   :  Cannot convert value of type '[UIControlState]' to expected argument type 'UIControlState'

Comment: I used UIControlState.ArrayLiteralElement(allControlStates) instead of [] But again got the same result

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate font again.
2. Download and copy correct code.
3. Remove the old font file and add new font file (.ttf) to the app.
4. Ensure you have included font to `Fonts provided by application` list in info.plist.
5. Use new code.

`setTitleTextAttributes(<#T##attributes: [String : Any]?##[String : Any]?#>, for: <#T##UIControlState#>)`

```
    let dictionary = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "icomoon", size: 25)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red]

    menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(dictionary, for: .normal)
    menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(dictionary, for: .disabled)
    menuButton.setTitleTextAttributes(dictionary, for: .highlighted)
```

Comment: again I received the same result Just like the picture here

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Can you try replacing `publicSVGAssets().menu` with some string (eg. menu)?

Comment: this variable is public and its equal to this 
public var menu = "\u{e905}"

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi The code you have mentioned is for what you are getting.

Comment: I went to moonIcon site and convert my images to font and use them in my code

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi see updated answer, it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181593/discussion-between-satish-and-saeed-rahmatolahi).